# RHEL:Change Screen Resolution of Virtual Console

Tags: rhel, console, tty

I am working on a RHEL 6.3 Workstation. And the monitor is a HD AOC Monitor. Problem I am facing is whenever this machine starts up, it runs with maximum screen resolution. It is a big screen and therefore causing eye-strain while I am working on virtual terminal (accessed by typing ALT+CTRL+(F1-F6)). How can I resolve this issue?

```
[root@manmatha grub]# uname -a
Linux manmatha 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 20 12:17:37 EST 2013
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228156/how-can-i-live-change-the-tty-rows-and-columns

Answer (score 2):

Yes.after doing a large amount of browsing, i got this

add a parameter

```
video=XRES x YRES
```

to the kernel parameter list while the system boots up.To make it permanent you may change the
corresponding kernel's parameter list.Usually it resides in-

```
/boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Alternatively you can use the

```
fbset
```

tool.Use

```
<su>yum install fbset
```

or similar commands to install it on your system.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please take a moment to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Might try with [the vga= kernel parameter](http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html)

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried xrandr command?

```
xrandr -s 1024x768
xrandr -s 1600x900
```

..to whatever you like.

Comment: `xrandr` is an interface to RandR, which is an extension to the X Window System.

Comment: Yes and it is an RH Workstation so he's supposedly on X?

Comment: not on virtual consoles 1-6