# How can I live-change the TTY rows and columns?

Tags: tty

> This is a question about Linux running on a Compulab device named
>   [Utilite Pro](http://www.compulab.co.il/utilite-computer/web/utilite-pro-specifications), but I think it is worth the price to ask this
>   question here to get it solved for any platform (if possible).

I use to work with [ConSpy](http://conspy.sourceforge.net/), a wonderful **remote control** program for the **TTY text** mode consoles.
If I boot my Utilite to **Ubuntu 12.04** with **HDMI cable connected** to my 720p home screen, I can remotely connect to any TTY, for example the first TTY:

```
# conspy 1
```

But if I **disconnect** the cable and reboot:

```
luis@utilite-desktop:~$ sudo conspy 1
conspy: screen too large.  I only handle up to 200x80.
```

It seems the **resolution goes up to 1080p**, and so columns/rows in TTY text mode are too big for ConSpy to manage them.

Same results with Kali v1.0.9.

For what I have read, it seems (incredibly, but it is true) that Linux has terrible problems to change the text mode resolution.
All the methods I have found require for **GRUB modifications**, but Utilite uses **U-Boot** instead of GRUB, and it is too cryptic for me to manage (never talk about the risk of saving data to flash).

Isn't there any **simpler method to change the TTY** text resolution (this is: rows and columns)?

I have tried:

```
# nano /etc/rc.local
```

... and then adding:

```
stty cols 83 rows 40
```

But results stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

It’s unclear which namely text buffer dimension is *too large* for ConSpy (`stty --all` or so isn’t provided), so recommendations about both number of text lines and cpl follow.

There are different parameters about a TUI console:

- *video* mode (i. e. how many scan lines × screen width (in dots));
- how many *character boxes* are there (i. e. text lines × cpl).

Generally:
   text lines = scan lines / character height
   cpl = screen width (in dots) / character width
Character height and width are in dots. Division is integer, where remainder is dropped.

To decrease number of text lines, load a font with greater character height. To decrease cpl (characters per line), load a font with character width 12 or more. For example:

```
 setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-TerminusBold24x12.psf.gz
```

(although IMHO Terminus is ugly in many respects).

On Ubuntu, a custom `/etc/init/console-setup.conf` script may be manufactured, to be executed on boot. Namely, instead of

```
exec loadkeys /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
```

one may write

```
script
    setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-TerminusBold24x12.psf.gz
    loadkeys /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
end script
```

Note that cached.kmap.gz is a [keyboard-layout](/questions/tagged/keyboard-layout) (keymap) and doesn’t interfere with fonts. It is not necessary to execute `setfont` namely from “console-setup.conf”. Because of the [meaning of the term “console”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228050/how-are-virtual-consoles-related-to-traditional-computer-terminals) that choice seems logical.
*Update:* There is `/etc/init/console-font.conf` task in Ubuntu.

Or read [this stuff at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548522/resize-font-on-boot-message-screen-and-console), maybe will find something of use.

Most recommendations above assume framebuffer (`fbdev`) driver enabled. Also, in this case, the `fbset` command without arguments (or `sudo fbset` from a user shell) reports geometry of the current video mode, as:
   `geometry` *screen_width* *scan_lines* …

In [hardware VGA-like mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode), obsolete in modern Linuxes, maximal character width is 9. So one can decrease cpl (characters per line) only by enabling a non-standard (decreased) screen width, hence non-standard mode with decreased pixel clock frequency. It isn’t always possible and safe.

---

One more note about text lines × cpl at Linux virtual consoles. These values can be obtained with
    `sudo od -t u1 -N 2 /dev/vcsa`*number*
The first decimal number is text lines and the second is cpl. See vcs(4) and od(1) for explanations how it works.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting Stuff, Incnis Mrsi. Is there a method to guess the actual `scan lines` and `screen width` values? If possible without X started, but methods needing X could be fine too.

Comment: @Sopalajo de Arrierez: answer updated.

Comment: Fine! The `fbset` command seems the proper way to make calculations here. Could you please expand on the `cached.kmap.gz` file? I don't get its meaning. Is it some sort of cache for the last used font?

Comment: @Sopalajo: cached.kmap.gz is keyboard layout, and doesn’t interfere with fonts. Ī̲ suggest to bundle two tasks together because keyboard and monitor constitute together an entity known as the system console.

Comment: @Sopalajo: There is `/etc/init/console-font.conf` task in Ubuntu. Possibly, proper setup of this would be preferential over modifying console-setup.conf.